# Set dtype for Dataframe got from_records

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm getting a data from `DB`, where `phone_number` data starts with `0`.
I'm changing this data to a `dataframe` like this

```py
header = ["phone_number", etc...]

cursor = self.connect_kikan_db()
cursor.execute(self.config['KOKYAKU_SQL'])
lst = cursor.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(lst, columns=header)
```

But when I insert the `lst` to the `dataframe` my `phone_number` column contains numbers without front 0 (zero) because it automatically changing the column type to `int` and instead of `0908566398` my values are `908566398` (but I'm not sure if all data contains 0 so I can't just append it there)

Comment: is it possible when retrieving the data to cast to string type? within sql?

Comment: I'm getting the data from `Microsoft SQL Server` like `select number, name from V_M` Do you think it is possible to cast it there?

Comment: Are you sure this is a pandas problem? [`pd.DataFrame.from_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) does not coerce strings to float.

Comment: @Michael Delgado I got it! there was a problem when I'm editing that df bellow this... thanks for the coment!

Comment: Definitely! glad it helped :)

Comment: If you think the solution is generally useful, you could post the full extent of your issue and then answer it yourself. But if it was totally unrelated or if it was just a minor bug, you can go ahead and close the question.